# Java program execution (let's not compilcate things)

Tags: java

I want to check if what I've learnt about Java basics is correct or not. Kindly correct me where I'm wrong.

When we compile/build a program: An object (.class) file corresponding the the source file is generated.

Now, when we run, this is passed to the JVM. The JVM also loads the necessary library files (the import files at the top) and using these two, it directly runs the program, no intermediate executable file is produced, right?

Comment: It looks for those imports on the _class path_, a list of .jar files and .class directories. But right, the JVM "links" other classes. The Java byte code can then be interpreted by the JVM. A hotspot compiler will translate part of the java byte code to machine code.

Comment: Yes, but the details are a bit different, an "import" is not a concept which is carried over to the class file. Imports only declare string shortcuts in the source. Class files declare dependencies with directly specifying the full class names on the places where they are needed.

Comment: Maybe.  The JIT (Just In Time) compiler does compile Java byte codes (the .class files) into machine executable.  This is an implementation detail of the JVM (it could choose to interpret the byte codes directly) and so usually isn't included in a high-level overview of byte code execution, but all modern JVMs do it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I think you have the correct sequence. This is the slightly more complicated system. First it generates a class from the .java file and then it goes through this process.

[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you buddy. That was very detailed. Appreciate. :)

Answer (score 0):

No files are created, but modern JVMs generate native code from the class files rather than interpreting directly from the class files.